# How do we determine 0M spot rate for 3M libor?

Tags: interest-rates, libor

Say I have a 3M libor curve constructed from a bunch of 3M FRAs, so I have a 3M spot rate, a 6M spot rate, a 9M spot rate, etc.

For points in-between, say 4M, I would have to interpolate between the 3M and 6M points.

But how would I interpolate a 2M point? That would require a 0M spot rate, i.e. the instantenous rate -- how do I get that?

Comment: If you construct your curve properly, you don't have the 6m and 9m spot rate. You have a set of 3m libor rates at dates in the future. Getting an instantaneous rate does not work with a curve that references 3m.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex indicates, these are not 6M/9M spot rates but a term structure of 3M Libor (zero) rates.

What you're describing happens quite often when determining the fixing for a stub period that is unequal to the reset frequency. See [here](https://www.isda.org/a/aWkgE/Linear-interpolation-04022022.pdf) a description and example of the methodology that is generally applied in ISDA contracts.